# Не получается прочитать txt фаил C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ооп

делаю курсовую работу, нужно прочитать строки из txt файла
но код жалуется на то что не может найти фаил
сам код :

```
void start()
    {
        var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(65001);
        try
        {//по идеи он сейчас должен прочитать фаил, но я не знаю работает ли это 
            Read = new System.IO.StreamReader(
                System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +
                                                             @"\ t", encoding);
```

расположение файла:
C:\Users\Пользователь\source\repos\Learn\Learn\bin\Debug\t.txt

Comment: `@"\ t"` -> `@"\t.txt"`, а лучше `Path.Join(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"t.txt")` вместо "сложения"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`65001` - это UTF8, эта кодировка используется по умолчанию, ее не надо явно указывать в методах работы с файлами.

Но если все-таки надо, то обратиться к этой кодировке можно вот так:

```cs
var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

А вообще прочитать файл в строчку можно проще.

```cs
string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Enviroment.CurrentDirectory, "t.txt"));
```

---

Научитесь подключать пространства имен, так код будет выглядеть проще, в начале C# файла укажите

```cs
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Спасибо Огромное ты мне очень помог